# Reference request: Explicit solution of Fredholm integral equations of the second kind

Tags: reference-request, integral-operators

I am looking for explicit solutions of the following Fredholm integral equation of the second kind
$$
\phi(t) = 1 + \int_0^1 G(|t-s|) \phi(s) ds, \qquad t \in [0,1],
$$
for specific kernels $G$, e.g. for $G(t) = \frac1{1+t}$, $G(t) = - \log t$ or $G(t) = t^{-1/2}.$

For $G(t) = e^{-\rho t}, \rho > 0,$ I am able to do this by converting the problem to an ordinary differential equation. But I am stuck with all other kernels I have looked at.

Do you know published results on this?